# Live server doesn't load img from css

Tags: html, css, image

I made a parallax website but it doesn't load any images everything else from css does load except the images . Nothing worked so far . Don't know if there is problem in the code or in the server .

[html and css codes](http://www.cssdesk.com/kRxb6)

[image: error]

[404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSSSg.png)

[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfkMY.png)

[Site is loaded but photos arent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEs5M.png)

Comment: where are your images and your css stored relative to the html document?

Comment: What is the response code?

Comment: Please provide your code structure including images

Answer (score 0):

problem you have here is that images aren't getting the right path.

I should understand the current file structure to give you a proper answer:

Let's say you have:

- index.html
- images/main.png
- styles/style.css

If this is the case. You are calling the image from the root, because index.html is located there.

So you can try calling the image like this:

```
.pimg1{background-image: url('/images/main.png');}
```

If this doesn't work, you can do the following:

```
.pimg1{background-image: url('./images/main.png');}
```

The **./** will always go to the root and then it will look for the directory **images/** This will help you with sites that has subfolders urls.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The quotations around the image urls are a handy addition to the original code.